# How to set the Label & Value of a Dojo List Text Box using client side script

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I can set the "value" using the script below.

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="inputText" value="#{document1.FormTitle}" displayLabel="true" multipleSeparator="##"></xe:djextListTextBox>

<xp:button value="Set Value" id="b1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var id = "#{id:inputText}";
        dijit.byId( id ).set( "value", "Value 1##Value 2" );        
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

But what I would like to do is set a label to display and have another value in the background.
Essentially duplicating the functionality displayed below.

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox14" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true" defaultValue="1,3" value="#{document1.Test}"
    displayLabel="true" title="Multiple Values with labels">
</xe:djextListTextBox>
<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker15" for="djextListTextBox14" pickerText="Add" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker labelSeparator="|" valueList="Value1|1,Value2|2,Value3|3,Value4|4" valueListSeparator=","></xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

Comment: Can you use 'displayedValue' to do a .set("displayedValue", "Value")?

Comment: That would be nice but unfortunately no (tried it).  As this is provided be the extLib my guess is they have an extended method but I cant find it.  It would have to work like  ...set( "Value1,Value2", "Label2,Label2" )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define labels for `xe:djextListTextBox` on client side with

```
dijit.byId(id).set("labels", {"value1":"label1","value2":"label2",...});
```

Your example would look like this then:

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="inputText" value="#{document1.FormTitle}" 
      displayLabel="true" multipleSeparator="##">
</xe:djextListTextBox>
<xp:button value="Set Value" id="b1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var id = "#{id:inputText}";
            dijit.byId(id).set("labels", {"Value 1":"Label 1", "Value 2":"Label 2"});
            dijit.byId(id).set("value", "Value 1##Value 2");        
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```